# How to authenticate a react-native app offline

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Am trying to make an app that runs both online and offline but i want my user to be authenticated or to be logged in once. So after the initial login i want them not to be able to see the login form again, i want to show them a new part of the app. They should be only to see the login form only when they decide to logout. My problem is that it would have been easier for me to do this if they are always online but they might be offline too so i just need them to login once and next time they boot up the app they wont see the login form again rather they would see something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could save an kind of "userIsAuthenticated"-Flag to local storage (see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html).

Based on this flag you could decide which screen the user see on startup.

But be aware, it could drive your Users crazy, if they have allways to relogin, if the network-connection (maybe cause of bad 3g/4g) was Interrupted.

You also give a notice if a user is offline, that they have to be online to use this app.

BTW: To request if a user has Network-Connection you can use: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.48/docs/netinfo.html#netinfo.

Don't forget to set permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` to be allowed to use the request.

Answer (score 0):

There is no authentication offline. Authentication is made so that the server-side makes sure it is used by a given identity because you can never trust the client-side. If there is no server-side, there is no authentication process.

If you just want to let the user use your application, even though he is online, why don't you store a local copy of the user profile within the local storage after a successful authentication? (with only non critical data of course).
This way, your application can rely on its memory to fetch the user profile and not the server while it is offline.

Comment: There are applications running in the local network and require authentication/ authorization.

Comment: Having a local network is not being offline, it is being online, just not on the whole web. The authentication process requests a check by a trusted device, which is a server you control, on a local network or on internet. Being offline, there is only the client device and you cannot trust it because the user can always hack it, one way or another, the authentication would be easy to break.